# Run Jar Using Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell

So I have a Java file that needs this following string to run.

```
java --classpath=$CLASSPATH:/path/to/jradius-client.jar net.sourceforge.jradiusclient.TestRadiusClient hostname authport acctport shared-secret username password
```

What I need to do is to write a script that uses space separated words from a certain `textFile.txt` and use each of the words in place of `shared-secret`. If it's a success, print the word.

What I have till now is:

```
#!/bin/bash

java --classpath=$CLASSPATH:/path/to/jradius-client.jar net.sourceforge.jradiusclient.TestRadiusClient "val" 1812 1813 shared-secret username password

exit $?
```

What I want is something like this (in Java like pseudo-code, I have no bash experience :( ):

```
String s = Words From Text File As String
String[] words = s.split("\\W+");
for(word : words){
    try and run The JAva .jar File With Params X, Y, word, Z
        success? print word
}
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: The frist result from https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=bash+read+words+from+text+file is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931915/how-can-i-read-words-instead-of-lines-from-a-file and the second is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719628/how-to-read-word-by-word-from-a-file-in-a-for-loop  Did neither of them help you?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah This is my first bash code kind of, I will try working on them. Sorry if the question is very naive.

Comment: I didn't meant that.  I just meant that if they didn't work if would be helpful to know why so that my answer wouldn't tell you something you had already tried.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I read it, but my low experience really comes in the way of an workable implementation. Thank you so much for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea for the loop taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7721320/2193968

```
for word in $(<textFile.txt)
do
    java --classpath=$CLASSPATH:/path/to/jradius-client.jar net.sourceforge.jradiusclient.TestRadiusClient hostname authport acctport $word username password
done
```

This will read every word from every line in textfile.txt and put it into `word` and then run the command substituting `$word` with the value read from the file.

Comment: Thank you so much. So I should run it `sh script.sh textFile.txt`? Thanks.

Comment: @jeet The script hardcodes the name of the text file.  If you need it to be passed on the command line I can do that.

Comment: No, thanks a lot. this works fine :) Thanks again for the help.